# How to move then delete field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to move a field from one table to another and then delete it from the first table.  The problem I am having is that it moves the data fine, but it is not deleting it from the first table.

Here is my code:

```
"INSERT INTO out_tickets SELECT * FROM tickets";
        "DELETE FROM tickets WHERE * FROM tickets";
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Updated Code:

```
<?php
// Process delete operation after confirmation
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])){
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Prepare a select statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO out_tickets SELECT * FROM tickets";
        "DELETE FROM tickets";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

    // Set parameters
    $param_id = trim($_POST["id"]);

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        // Records deleted successfully. Redirect to landing page
        header("location: technical.php");
        exit();
    } else{
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }
}
```

Comment: The information is lacking a bit. Is the code made using PDO? Is the SQL Query is just declared inside a single variable? (Multi query)

Comment: Also your syntax for delete is wrong. There's no need for *. You could just say. DELETE FROM tickets and everything will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you trying to move **ALL** columns from one table (t1) to another table (t2) with same structure (or to table, that contain same columns like in first) and than you want to delete data from table1 that you moved to t2?
If correct use next SQL

```
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM t1;
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE 1;
```

Comment: Thanks,  I am actually trying to move and then delete a specific row from one table1 to table2 then delete that entry from table one.  (the id's will be different)

Comment: Is column that you trying to move already exists in table2? In this case you need to execute: 
DELETE 
FROM t1

INNER JOIN t2 
  ON t1.id = t2.id (or your clause)

WHERE t2.column = (your clause);
Sorry, is my explanation is clear?

Comment: No it does not exist,  basically i just need to move the data from table1 to table2 then delete the selected data from table1

Comment: In that case you firstly need to create column(s) at table2:

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you there.  I have a second table with exact same rows as table1

Comment: So i can move it but it doesnt want to delete the selected row from table1 after it has been moved

Comment: I see ... the problem is that both of this tables contain different ID's. Do you have any another unique columns in this tables?In general you need to execute DELETE FROM t1 WHERE column_a IN (select column_a from t2 where <your clause>) And also as I see in your code, you need to execute DELETE in separated query!

Comment: I've checked your code and I think that problem in two requests by one mysqli_stmt_execute.  $sql = "INSERT INTO out_tickets SELECT * FROM tickets;         DELETE FROM tickets";
 Try to do it like $moveSql = "INSERT INTO out_tickets SELECT * FROM"; mysqli_stmt_execute($moveSql); $deleteSql = "DELETE FROM tickets"; mysqli_stmt_execute($deleteSql);